# How to set Chronos job schedule to run only 4 times every day?

Tags: cron, scheduled-tasks, mesos, cron-task, mesos-chronos

We have a requirement where a particular chronos(https://mesos.github.io/chronos/) job has to be run every 3 hours a day starting from morning 8 AM. So total 4 runs i.e. 8AM, 11AM, 2PM, 5PM and no runs after that. It should repeat every day. How to set such schedule in Chronos? Is it possible?